# Angular 6 ng serve is running completely but ng build is throwing an error

Tags: angular

> ERROR in @angular\common\http\http.ts(62,2): Error during template compile ttpClient'
>   Function calls are not supported in decorators but '?makeDecorator' was c
>   in 'Injectable'
>   'Injectable' calls '?makeDecorator'.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451
>   not redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   node_modules/adal-angular5/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mo
>   ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.

Comment: It looks like some of the lines of that error message have been truncated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for one of the libraries, added the below and it worked. Check the library which is failing, and try adding that to package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
     "@angular/common": ">=X.X.X"
}
```